# Does my sound sound good?

Tags: usage, spoken-english

Let's say I am playing an online video game where I need to use my microphone for chatting with people. For checking if the people who are in the same game as me get my voice(sound) properly (I mean for checking if the sound they get from me is clear, if it is buzzy or not, if it is cutting in and out or not, if its volume is too high or not etc.), is it wrong if I say "Does my sound sound good?", or do I have to say "Does my voice sound good?" using the word "voice" instead?

In my opinion, in this context it is better if I say "Does my sound sound good?" or "How is my sound?" or "How does my sound sound?" or "Is my sound good?", "How is the quality of my sound" etc. by using the word "sound" instead of the word "voice" since I don't exactly ask about my voice but the quality of the sound they get from me. What they hear is not exactly my voice in this context (a voice can't buzz, can't cut in and out etc.) They are getting an electronic sound from me and I am asking about its quality. They get a "sound" from me. I am not asking a question exactly about my "voice" in that context.

In a context where I speak face to face with a person, it would be wrong to say "Does my sound sound good", "Is my sound good?" etc. by using "sound" instead of "voice" as far as I know. But in that situation where I use a microphone while playing a video game, it is not wrong to say "sound" instead of "voice" I guess.

What do you think about this? I think that it is probably better to use "sound" in this context. Because using the word "voice" can cause ambiguity. If I say "How does my voice sound" in the context I told you about, it can be understood as a question about like the beauty of my voice. But if I say "my sound" instead, it has only one meaning. It is understood only as a question about the clearness, the volume etc. of the sound my microphone carries.

Comment: To really simply your quandary, you could simply say: *Sound check; 1-2-3...*

Answer (score 1):

The distinction you are making between "voice" and "sound" is not correct.

I would avoid the question "Does my sound sound good?" It is confusing.

In the actual situation I would ask "Am I coming through loud and clear?" or "Can you all hear me clearly?" or "Is my mic working properly?" There are lots of ways to ask this.

"My sound" is an unusual expression. Literally it could mean all the noises that the body makes: voice, cracking joints, farts... But when someone talks about "my sound" they normally mean "the kind of music that I like to listen to". But its not a common expression.

> My sound is Acid Jazz and punk fusion.

However, if you are actually having a conversation with someone over a microphone, then "Does my voice sound good" would be understood, given the context.

Comment: also "Is my audio ok?"  "Is my volume good?"

Comment: "Is my audio ok?" is fine. "is my **mic** volume good?" because if someone asked "is my volume good" they would be understood based on context, but in general _volume_ refers to your audio output volume (ie speakers).

Answer (score 0):

> Can you hear me?

Is an extremely common expression in the US.

If you feel the need to use audio or sound, *audio* is what you want to use for this question.

> Is my audio clear?
>
> Is my audio coming through clearly?